# How to change keyboard layout shortcut to ctrl+shift on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I am used to use ctrl+shift to change keyboard layout. I found how to do change keyboard layout :

[image]

However, I can't set crtl+shift, for example, I can set only ctrl+tab or ctrl+c or ctrl+shift+w etc but can't only ctrt+shift. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are running the Gnome Desktop Environment. If so, you can do this with the Tweak Tool. Search for and run the tweak tool, select Typing>Switching to another layout and tick the box for Ctrl+Shift.

Comment: I tried it, but ctrl+shift still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a second keyboard layout added? It is working for me. It doesn't show the on screen change like the regular shortcut does, but it should change in the top right

Comment: I found the problem: `#dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options` gave the following output : `['grp:rctrl_shift', 'grp:ctrl_shift_toggle']`, so I did `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:ctrl_shift_toggle']"`

Answer (score 0):

A thing that happen to me once is (for my work) I needed to edit a field on a web page with Ctrl+Alt+Shift. This combination of keys was working on a Doze machine but not on a Nux machine. The culprit was the default keyboard layout itself. I changed it. So if you can change your defualt keyboard layout.